# SSE multiplication of 4 32-bit integers

Tags: x86, sse, simd, multiplication, sse2

How to multiply four 32-bit integers by another 4 integers?
I didn't find any instruction which can do it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you need *signed* 32x32 bit integer multiplication then the following example at [software.intel.com](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/SSE2-signed-32bit-integer-multiplication/m-p/784255) looks like it should do what you want:

```c
static inline __m128i muly(const __m128i &a, const __m128i &b)
{
    __m128i tmp1 = _mm_mul_epu32(a,b); /* mul 2,0*/
    __m128i tmp2 = _mm_mul_epu32( _mm_srli_si128(a,4), _mm_srli_si128(b,4)); /* mul 3,1 */
    return _mm_unpacklo_epi32(_mm_shuffle_epi32(tmp1, _MM_SHUFFLE (0,0,2,0)), _mm_shuffle_epi32(tmp2, _MM_SHUFFLE (0,0,2,0))); /* shuffle results to [63..0] and pack */
}
```

You might want to have two builds - one for old CPUs and one for recent CPUs, in which case you could do the following:

```c
static inline __m128i muly(const __m128i &a, const __m128i &b)
{
#ifdef __SSE4_1__  // modern CPU - use SSE 4.1
    return _mm_mullo_epi32(a, b);
#else               // old CPU - use SSE 2
    __m128i tmp1 = _mm_mul_epu32(a,b); /* mul 2,0*/
    __m128i tmp2 = _mm_mul_epu32( _mm_srli_si128(a,4), _mm_srli_si128(b,4)); /* mul 3,1 */
    return _mm_unpacklo_epi32(_mm_shuffle_epi32(tmp1, _MM_SHUFFLE (0,0,2,0)), _mm_shuffle_epi32(tmp2, _MM_SHUFFLE (0,0,2,0))); /* shuffle results to [63..0] and pack */
#endif
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Funny you made exactly the same typo I had once in my code: It should be _____SSE4_1_____ (no underscore between E and 4). Annoying, because you don't notice it easily - the program runs perfect as long as the alternate code path is ok

Comment: @drhirsch: thanks for fixing that - in real code I tend to use `__MNI__`, `__SNI__`, etc - mainly for historical reasons, but it's also less prone to simple errors such as the above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now, if only there was a similar trick for replacing `_mm_insert_epi32` on a CPU with SSE2 only...

Comment: Note that the "old CPU path" may be actually slower than an explicit `for` loop over the 4 integers - definitely not faster on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the reason of using `epu32` instead of `epi32` in the multiplication (assuming signed integers are passed)?

Comment: @fabian: think about how you learned to do long hand (decimal) multiplication in school: when you work through the columns you are doing unsigned multiplication for all but the leftmost column, e.g. for -12x34 you start with 4x2=8 (unsigned!). We are not calculating the leftmost columns (the high order 32 bits) here, so we don't need to worry about signed multiplication.

Answer (score 9):

[PMULLD](http://www.tptp.cc/mirrors/siyobik.info/instruction/PMULLD.html), from SSE 4.1, does that.

The description is slightly misleading, it talks about signed multiplication, but since it only stores the lower 32bits, it's really a sign-oblivious instruction that you can use for both, just like `IMUL`.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to use only SSE 2 instructions?

Comment: `_mm_mullo_epi32` if you'd rather use intrinsics than raw assembly

Comment: @Leviathan Yes, but you need several instructions. Depending on the architecture, four `imul` are possibly faster and simpler

Comment: Why only SSE2 ? Do you really need to support > 10 year old CPUs ?

Comment: @PaulR There are still a lot of AMDs out there. Only Bulldozer supports SSSE3 and above.

Comment: Opteron *et al* support SSE3 though (not that this helps much in this particular case).