# SSE Instructions

Tags: c, intel, sse

I have a question regarding SSE instruction.

I hope this is the right place to ask such a question if not pls let me know and I will remove this question.

My goal is to use SSE instructions to execute calculations on 3 chars in parallel.

I have a typedef struct which has the attribute that it is packed

```
typedef struct
{
        unsigned char x;
        unsigned char y;
        unsigned char z;
} __attribute__((packed)) Number;
```

For each char I have to go through a certain calculation.

As an example:

```
((Number[0].x * 20)  / 256);
```

I have to do a small calculation for every char and then add them together.

Since I have to write the code in assembly I have already done some research and stumble upon this instruction:

```
__m128i _mm_add_epi8 (__m128i a, __m128i b)
```

As far as I am concerned this should add two values (who have each the size of 8 bytes) together and save the result.

At least that's how I understand it:
[From this link](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2&expand=106)

But since we only add two values together this defeats the whole purpose of executing multiple instructions at once.

Any help would be very apricated.
Kind regards!

Comment: That's SSE not SEE. Yes, it does add two values, but it does 16 pairs at once. You could use 3 of those to perform calculation for 16 `Number` instances.

Comment: SEE? Do you mean SSE?

Comment: And if you want to divide by 256, you're going to need a larger type than char...

Comment: you dont think the compiler will do that for you , modern compilers are wickedly good at optimization.

Comment: @pm100, you'd think so, but they are not that hot when dealing with `char`s (unless there's an option i'm forgetting): https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/htGiqy

Comment: None of this is assember code. Intrinsics are still C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could provide more information about how you're actually using this it might be possible to better optimize it, but based on what you wrote I guess you'd want something like `_mm_srli_epi32(_mm_mullo_epi32(_mm_set_epi32(n.x, n.y, n.z, 0), _mm_set1_epi32(20)), 8)`.  It requires SSE 4.1, but if you want something which works for SSE 2 see [SSE multiplication of 4 32-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500766/sse-multiplication-of-4-32-bit-integers) for a `_mm_mullo_epi32` replacement.

You didn't specify what you want to do with the result, but you can use something like `((int*) &r_sse)[i]` to access the results, where `i` is 1 for z, 2 for y, and 1 for x.

Comment: I am using it to convert an Image to gray. I have 3 chars red, blue and green and each of them has to go through a certain calculation and then need to be added together. The result of the calculation is then passed to each char(so every char gets the same value) and the result should be a gray pixel.

Comment: `_mm_mullo_epi32` is kind of slow though, can't we use 16bit arithmetic here?